# unexpected logistic regression coefficients - opposite to chi square/cross tabs

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm interpreting the coefficients of a regression with all categorical variables and all but one make sense, in that I was expecting the association/direction from my descriptive statistics. I know that the regression controls for other variables, but one coefficient makes no sense - in other words the opposite to what I was expecting. It's social science, so the model itself is weak (can't actually predict using just these variables) but I'm interpreting the coefficients anyway as per my supervisors advice. I was expecting multicollinearity but correlations not showing anything out of the ordinary. My sample size is enormous (25,000). 
Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a question as to whether there is a *suppressor* effect going on.  Would help to have things quantified:  how collinear are the predictors, how much does the key coefficient change, how weak is the whole model.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Rolando2. Sorry I didn't see it until now! Yes the key coefficient changes from .361 (which is roughly what I would expect) to -.048 when the other predictor is added. The two variables are correlated at -.270. The whole model only has an r2 of .11...